# C Function Prototype

Tags: c

Learning C here, and I'm pretty confused on how to use function prototypes.

I'm mainly having a problem calling the function into main. I'm sure I have something messed up in here because all this does is print whatever's in memory.

Thank you for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>


double source_volt(double vs);


int main()
{
    double source_volt(double vs);
    double vs;
    printf("%lf", vs);
    return 0;
}


double source_volt(double vs)
{

    int valid = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter source voltage Vs in volts: ");
        scanf("%lf", &vs);

        if (vs < 0 || vs > 100)
        {
            valid = 0;
            printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.\n");
        }
        else
            valid = 1;
    }while(!valid);
    return vs;
}
```

Comment: You have a read a textbook about `function declaration`, `function definition`, `how to call a function` etc. Answering this question is certainly not going to help as you seem to lack the basic understanding of functions.

Comment: Why does the `source_volt` is passed a parameter by value ? I think you want to pass the address of it instead and make the function return type void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is not working for you:

```
int main()
{
    double source_volt(double vs); //You already declared the function, 
                                   //you dont need the doubles
    double vs;
    printf("%lf", vs);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead:

```
int main()
{
    double vs;
    vs = double source_volt(vs); //The double keyword is gone
    printf("%lf", vs);
    return 0;
}
```

But really, you don't need an argument at all in source volt.

You could rewrite *that* function to:

```
double source_volt(void)
{
    double vs;
    int valid = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter source voltage Vs in volts: ");
        scanf("%lf", &vs);

        if (vs < 0 || vs > 100)
        {
            valid = 0;
            printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.\n");
        }
        else
            valid = 1;
    }while(!valid);
    return vs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line inside main `double source_volt(double vs);` actually redeclares the function.  And then `vs` in main is being used without initializing it.

The function `source_volt` as it's defined would be called like so:

```
double vs;
vs = source_volt( vs );
```

However, I'd also like to point out that you're not gaining anything by passing a double into tho function.   You could declare a local variable in `source_volt` and return it to get the same results.